# Azure Service Bus: What is difference between DeadLetterQueue and DeferQueue?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am a little bit confused about DeadLetterQueue and DeferQueue in Azure Service Bus. What is the difference between them, and which scenario do we prefer, DeadLetterQueue and DeferQueue? Also, which performs better between them?

Comment: Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues

Comment: Got it. Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting @David comment as answer
Please refer to below document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral